# How about a poetry analysis site?

Tags: feature-request

I am aware that SE sites are not fit for topics that are based more on 'opinion' than on fact. However, we could consider an exception and allow people to post poetry that they are finding hard to understand. And with the language and literature experts that we have available with us on SE, a lot of learners and enthusiasts alike can benefit from their expertise.

I personally find it hard to understand some English poems, such as "An Ode to Autumn" by Keats. So, it would be great to discuss poetry with people who can decipher even the most hidden of metaphors.

Comment: You might find that some of the regulars in the [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com/)' [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/168/the-overlook-hotel) would be interested in this kind of discussion.

Comment: This topic has been raised quite recently, [Any EL&U appetite for a Q&A Poetry site?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4718/any-elu-appetite-for-a-qa-poetry-site), where you will find that a site has been proposed.

Comment: Wasn't there a literature.SE?

Answer (score 3):

In many ways, ELU.SE is already a poetry analysis site.
The best definition of poetry I've ever seen is in Chapter 111a in *Even Cowgirls Get The Blues*.
Here is that chapter, in its entirety:

---

> "Poetry is nothing more than an intensification or illumination of common objects and everyday events, until they shine with their singular nature, until we can experience their power, until we can follow their steps in the dance, until we can discern what parts they play in the Great Order of Love. 
>   How is this done? By fucking around with syntax.
>
> "Definitions are limiting. Limitations are deadening.
>   To limit oneself is a kind of suicide.
>   To limit another is a kind of murder.
>   To limit poetry is a Hiroshima of the human spirit.
>
> "***Danger! Radiation!
>
>          Unauthorized Personnel Not Allowed
>
>              On the Premises of Chapter 111a!***"

---

A great deal of what we do here in ELU is, straightforwardly, "fucking around with syntax."
Few of the texts we see here are Official Poetry, but some of them do approach this standard,
if not always by design.